# Why does Rust need to return static sizes?

Tags: garbage-collection, rust

I thought one of the big features of Rust is being a systems language comparable to C but with a garbage collector. If this is the case, why do you need to return values of a static size (or use `Box` from what I gather)?

Comment: [Rust does not have a garbage collector.](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/faq.html#is-rust-garbage-collected)

Comment: You can do this like atomic reference counters  to "sorta" accomplish things a garbage collector handles. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html

Comment: "a systems language comparable to C but with a garbage collector" that would be D, not Rust. Where did you read that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does Rust need to return static sizes?

Every value in every language needs to have a static size. That's how the compiler / interpreter / runtime / virtual machine / hardware knows how to access the bits that make up the value.

In many languages, every value is comparable to a Rust `Box`, so they all take up one or two pointer's worth of space. The statically-known size for those values allows a layer of indirection which can point to something with a runtime-determined size.

In Rust (and C, C++, probably other system languages), you can also directly store arbitrary values on the stack, unboxed. In these cases, you still need to know the size that the value will occupy.

This is a simplification, as some languages allow certain specific values to reside on the stack, while others "embed" certain value types inside of the fixed-size indirection. Tricks like these are usually for performance reasons.

> but with a garbage collector

[Rust **does not** have a garbage collector](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/faq.html#is-rust-garbage-collected). It does have *smart pointers* that deallocate resources when the pointer goes out of scope.

[`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) is the obvious smart pointer, but there's also [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html).